# I am not able to locate the files manually that I am getting from terminal "ls" output

Tags: linux, docker, directory, filesystems, ls

I installed docker container from [Githunb](https://github.com/ShixiangWang/install_GISTIC). It is working smoothly via run_docker.sh command. Everything is working as desired but I am not able to locate the input files present at directories mentioned in "run_docker.sh" script.

So I run the command as mentioned at Github page

```
(base) smtpn@smtpn-Nitro:~$ sudo docker run -it --rm --entrypoint bash shixiangwang/gistic
```

And then I use "ls" to check the files present in that directory

```
(base) root@3340d861afab:/opt/GISTIC# ls
```

The output list all directory, required to run docker. However, when I go to the directory `/opt/`   manually through nautilus or nemo file manager, I am not able to locate any directory/folder (hidden folder view is on) which I am getting from terminal output.
How can I see the same list of folders which I am getting from the terminal output?

It is very strange and do not know why it is happening.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I think you misunderstood how containers work. Their filesystems are stored in internal Docker directories but they are **not** your host filesystem.

Comment: @AymDev oh I see, It was first time I am using it. thank you so much for your help. Actually, I need to change "example" file provided with docker from my own file. I tried to change the location of the "example" file but it showing an error so I thought to replace it by going to listed folder. So How could I locate the files? Any idea? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @AymDev I am using this file https://github.com/ShixiangWang/install_GISTIC/blob/master/run_docker.sh and want to change the location of segmentationfile.txt at segfile=$GISTIC_LOC/examplefiles/segmentationfile.txt

Comment: @AmyDev my location of segmentationfile.txt is /home/smtpn/segmentationfile.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Containers are isolated from the host. Their filesystems are stored in internal Docker directories which you could locate for fun but shouldn't use to work with your containers.

If you need to share files or directories between your host and a container, you can make use of [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) which will map a file/directory from your host to one of a container

```sh
docker run -it --rm -v /home/smtpn:/some/dir/inside/container --entrypoint bash shixiangwang/gistic
```

> Notice the [-v](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#choose-the--v-or---mount-flag) option: `-v /home/smtpn:/some/dir/inside/container` (which is a basic example as I don't know what you're doing).
> It maps the `/home/smtpn` directory from the host to the `/some/dir/inside/container` directory inside the container. You can do the same for files.

I'm not sure that a volume will really solve your issues. If you need to make many changes to an image, you may also be interested in creating your own image by extending the actual one, by writing a [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/).

Comment: Yes You are right I found the location it is inside docker :) admin:///var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/M73GI4PPIRR2EMSLXCCE7EV6L2/opt/GISTIC/examplefiles/segmentationfile.txt

Comment: How can I change the file location from above to my local file location that is   /home/smtpn/install_GISTIC-master/segmentationfile.txt

Comment: @gupta I guess that the location from inside the container is `/opt/GISTIC/examplefiles/segmentationfile.txt` so the `-v` option would be `-v /home/smtpn/install_GISTIC-master/segmentationfile.txt:/opt/GISTIC/examplefiles/segmentationfile.txt` maybe ?